# How to have my app run on iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screens?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I use nib files, no story board.
My first view controller is a login screen. 
In it I have a few UIViews and I switch among them with setView.
The simulated metrics is 3.5
under one of the UIViews I have UIImageView, of size 320X480.
In viewDidLoad I identify iPhone 5 screen and change the size of the UIMageView to 320X1136. In the debugger I see that it has changed to the new size.
However, After I switch to the parent view of that UIImageView (using setView), it returns to be 320X480.
How can I force my UIImageView to be 320X1136 at run time?

Comment: are you mixing here the _non-retina_ width with the _retina_ height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether you have the default image file for iPhone 5 screen. check for Default-568h@2x.png file in project->resources.This will solve your problem. Even after that if the problem exists means please check whether autolayout is set for image view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autolayout noting but constraints for UIView and UIImageVIew.
No need to set the dimension for View programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add splach screen of size  Default-568h@2x.png  (640*1136).

or check the size for in app delegate and make 2 nibs one for iphone4 and one for iphone5

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    objopengames = [[Open_games alloc] initWithNibName:@"Open_games5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
}
else
{
    objopengames = [[Open_games alloc] initWithNibName:@"Open_games" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objopengames animated:YES];
```

Comment: the bundle can be `nil` if that'd refer to the `mainBundle`.